# How to check password hide characters?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-unittest

Hello i need help with checking password hide characters. I have to test a password field if length of a password is the same as the length of password hide characters. Is there any way to do it without OCR.
I know the password phrase and its length. Now i need to check if hide characters are the same length as passphrase.
For now my ide is to cut web element, and count cover characters (black circles instead of password) and then to check if length of this word is the same as the passphrase. Is there any other way to do it?
THX

Answer (score 0):

Thx for -3 points. Here is my code if anybody has same problem. Hope this helps

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import time
import cv2


password = '12345678'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('mysite.com')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(password)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
location = element.location
size = element.size
driver.save_screenshot("PageImage.png")
x = location['x']
y = location['y']
width = location['x']+size['width']
height = location['y']+size['height']
im = Image.open('PageImage.png')
im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
im.save('pass.png')
driver.quit()
passSlika = cv2.imread('pass.png', 0)
cv2.imwrite('pass.png', passSlika)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(passSlika, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
s1 = 3
s2 = 20
xcnts = []
for cnt in cnts:
    if s1<cv2.contourArea(cnt) <s2:
        xcnts.append(cnt)

#Minus one is because eye in design is one more dot
if (len(xcnts)-1 == len(password)):
    print('the same')
```